# Problems with grid view in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

I am displaying a table with user email ID and name in a GRID view in a ASP.NET web Page.
 I want a send mail button or link next to each row. SO that when I click the send mail button the useremail in that row will be copied and the page will be redirected to send mail page. How to do it?

BTW i am using MYSQL

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Probably it would be like this

```
<asp:GridView runat="Server" id="GrdVw_Email">
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email" DataFormatString="email.aspx?id={0}" DataText="SendEmail"/>
</asp:GridView>
```

i just put the code from my mind, but you should get the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HyperLink field:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="email" HeaderText="Mail To:" DataNavigateUrlFields="email" Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="SendMail.aspx?email={0}" SortExpression="email" />
```

hope Thisa helps